# Can PHP echo an element into Android?

Tags: javascript, php, android, html

While using HTML, Javascript, and PHP, I can make an HttpGet request to my MySQL database and then echo information back onto my HTML page, including actual elements such as buttons and tables.

```
echo "<button type='button'>$name</button>";
```

or

```
echo "<table><tr><td>$name</td><td>$age</td></tr></table>";
```

Can PHP echo elements after an HttpGet request onto my Android GUI?

Comment: From PHPs (the servers) point of view there is no difference between different clients, that is the whole purpose of using a standard protocol like http. That means yes, PHP can return whatever payload you want to a requesting client, be it html markup or whatever data at all. It is up to the client sides logic to make sense of such data and use it. That is nothing the server side has control over.

Comment: Thanks, I know.  What I'm asking is can Android take the information from PHP and use it to generate an element, like a button or table.

Comment: That depends on what platform you are building your app on. Different such platforms exist. Some are HTML based, then the answer obviously is yes, some are native, rich clients, java based in case of Android, in that case the immediate answer obviously is no, since such applications form a closed binary blob, buttons and other elements are generated different in such cases, not by markup. And certainly there are mixed platforms and you can make up your own strategy that allows to do whatever you want in the application you yourself programmed the moment it receives some string of information.

Comment: I'm developing an app with Android Studio and Java.  I can get PHP to echo text information onto my MainActivity.java, but I haven't been able to find any information on echoing actual elements.

Comment: As said: that is not possible. That is not how java works.

Comment: You have to understand the difference between an interpreted and a compiled platform. Both have advantages and disadvantages, but in general you cannot create GUI elements "on-the-fly" on a compiled platform, _unless_ you embed an interpreted module, like an HTML canvas for example, or you select from precompiled modules (dialogs for example) that you select based on the received information. but you can not directly "inject" some received code into your running application.

Comment: Ok, thanks.  I guess I'll have to come up with an alternative.

Comment: One hint: you will get better (more constructive) answers or help if you do not describe _how you might be able to_ achieve what you try to do but if you actually describe what exactly it is you _want to do_.